# My question is about how to rectify the 'env-path' is not recognized by internal or external command operable program or batchfile error

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, bitbucket, production-environment

After running react application with *npm start* I am getting error like: **'env-path' is not recognized by internal or external command operable program or batchfile.**
even i tried:  ***npm i***   and  ***npm i env-path*** commands but did not work.
I have cloned the react application from bit. Later I tried to run in vs code with npm start but it is showing error like that.

Answer (score 0):

for that have to change the version of node js to previous ones which can be handle.